# SQLITE3 Rotate Rows into columns

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to make a SQLITE3 query that joins two tables and then groups results together without losing columns.

Table A is a normal table, and Table B is supposed to be a dynamic array that Table A can use.

I am trying to get something like this to output
a_attr1|a_attr2|a_attr3|b_index1|b_value1|b_index2|b_value2|b_index3|b_value3

Instead I am getting...
a_attr1|a_attr2|a_attr3|b_index3|b_value3

Any idea how I can tweak my query to do that?

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  a_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
  a_attr1 INTEGER,
  a_attr2 INTEGER,
  a_attr3 VARCHAR,
);

CREATE TABLE B
(
    a_id INTEGER,
    b_index INTEGER,
    b_value INTEGER
);

CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT a_attr1, a_attr2, a_attr3, b_index, b_value
FROM A AS A
LEFT JOIN B AS B ON A.a_id = B.a_id
GROUP BY A.a_id;
```

Comment: There's no way to do this, and it sounds like a bad design. (Also the `GROUP BY A.a_id` is a no-op if A.a_id is unique)

Comment: Thank you. What makes this a bad design though?

Comment: You can't dynamically add or remove columns from each row; each query has a set number of columns for each row. Doing what you're asking would require that you have different amounts of columns per row, since each `A` row may have a different amount of `B` rows.